# Does the part 'that...' modify 'so' in a 'so...that' sentence?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

For example:

> So exhausted was she **that she went straight to bed**.

A common opinion sees 'that...' as an adverbial clause of result for 'exhausted'.

But, I think the part 'that she went straight to bed' modifies the degree adverb 'so', indicating how exhausted she was.

I don't know if I'm right. Any opinion will be appreciated!

Comment: The content clause "that she went straight to bed" is not a modifier but a complement licensed by the "so" that modifies "exhausted". More specifically, it is a 'indirect complement'.

Comment: Note that _that_ clauses are almost always complements, not modifiers.

Comment: Your example sentence is using an inversion, so maybe it would make the analysis easier to undo that inversion first, since I think the inversion is not what your question is about. The "standard" formulation of that sentence would be: "She was so exhausted that she went straight to bed." Notice that you can also add in more details if you want: "She was so exhausted after doing all that hard work that she went straight to bed."

Answer (score 1):

> *So exhausted was she* [*that she went straight to bed*].

The bracketed element, a declarative content clause (or *that* clause), is not a modifier but a complement in clause structure licensed by the "so" that modifies "exhausted".

Since such clauses are not licensed by the head word, but by an item embedded within some other dependent, they are known as 'indirect complements'.

Note that *that* clauses are virtually always complements, not modifiers.

Comment: Thank you very much! You said 'that' clauses are not licensed by the head word, but by an item embedded within some other dependent. I wonder what the item is and within which dependent it is embedded in the example sentence.

Comment: @Winter'sLove The "that" clause is licensed by the "so" that is embedded within the dependent item "so exhausted".

Comment: Right. _So/Such `X` that `S`_ is a common construction. _So_ for adjective `X` and _such_ for NP `X`, followed by a clause (`S`) introduced by the complementizer _that_ presenting the result of the unusual level of `X`. _So cold that the spit froze; such a weird suggestion that I forgot all about it._

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 3 ways to look at the given Sentence :

> So exhausted was she that she went straight to bed.

WordWeb has the ["SO"](https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=SO) Entry with around 10 variants :

> (1) To a very great extent or degree
> "the idea is so obvious"; "never been so happy"; "I love you so"; "my head aches so!"

> (4) To a certain unspecified extent or degree
> "I can only go so far with this student"; "can do only so much in a day"

> (7) (usually followed by 'that') to an extent or degree as expressed
> "he was so tired he could hardly stand"; "so dirty that it smells"

I have listed (1) , (4) & (7) which are relevant to the Question.

Going with (1) , "SO" can be taken like this :

> SO (very) exhausted was she that (hence) she went straight to bed.
> She was "SO" (very) exhausted that (hence) she went straight to bed.

Going with (4) , "SO" can be taken like this :

> SO (somewhat) exhausted was she that (hence) she went straight to bed.
> She was "SO" (somewhat) exhausted that (hence) she went straight to bed.

Going with (7) , "SO" can be taken like this :

> SO (to the extent expressed later) exhausted was she that (the tiredness extent) she went straight to bed.
> She went straight to bed ; "SO" (very) exhausted she was (the extent expressed earlier).

Hence your Interpretation (7) is Correct , but there are some other Interpretation may be valid too , in general.

Comment: Thank you very much! So, the head of the 'that' clause is 'so' whatever variant 'so' is?

Comment: Yes , That is Correct

Comment: The OP asked if the _that_ clause modified "so". It doesn't. Declarative content clauses (_that_ clauses) are always complements, not modifiers, since they must be licensed by some expression, in this case by "so".

Comment: @BillJ I ask the question in another way: What is the head of the 'that' clause? or What does the 'that' clause complement?

Comment: @Winter'sLove The head of a clause is always a verb, so it's "went". The "that" clause is complement of "exhausted", but it's licensed by "so".

Comment: @BillJ Thank you !  What is the difference between 'be headed by' and 'be licensed by'? Why does the 'that' clause complement 'exhausted' while is licensed by 'so'?

Comment: @Winter'sLove Usually, a complement is a complement of the head word, a verb, noun, adjective, or whatever. In the case of an 'indirect complement', the head and the licensor are not the same word. The "that" clause belongs in the adjective phrase with "exhausted" as head, but it is licensed by "so". We know that because if we drop the word "so" the sentence becomes ungrammatical.

Comment: I believe it's item (7) that applies in this case. It is to the degree that. I.e. "She was so exhausted that she went straight to bed" is the same as saying the more complicated: "She was exhausted to the extent or to the degree necessary that she went straight to bed."

Comment: Another example: "I filled up the balloon so much that it popped == I filled up the balloon (with air) to such an extent or such a degree that it (the balloon) popped." In normal conversations, we'd use the formulation so X that ... as this sounds less complicated. The formulation using words like to an extent or to a degree are appropriate for technical discussions, mathematical explanations, etc. Like if you are explaining the physical reason why a balloon pops or something like that.

Comment: I agree with that Interpretation , @Brandin , that is why I added the last line **"Hence your Interpretation (7) is Correct , but [....] some other Interpretation may be valid too , in general."**

Comment: Thank @Brandin and Prem for your wonderful discussion.  So, your opinion is that the 'that' clause complements the word 'so', but not 'exhausted'?

Comment: @Winter'sLove You can think of "so" and "that" as going together, like "from" and "to" (from A to B). But the "that" in "so ... that" can sometimes be omitted if it's clear. E.g. "she was so tired that she went to straight to bed" --> "she was so tired she went straight to bed." In that case, leaving out "that" is fine. If in doubt, retain the 'that' for clarity. If we employ the inversion, as in your original example: "So tired was she that she went straight to bed" then in this case, removing 'that' would probably make it unclear, so you'd best not omit it in this case.

Comment: @Brandin Thank you! I know 'so...that' is a fixed pattern. I just want to know what is the head of the 'that' clause in my original example. Is it 'exhausted' or 'so'?